# ngx-mapbox-gl Mapbox GL Popup with Feature layers and not with Markers

Tags: javascript, geojson

I am creating a Mapbox GL page using ngx-mapbox-gl. I am using GeoJson Feature layers to create clusters and individual points. My code is based from this example

https://wykks.github.io/ngx-mapbox-gl/demo/cluster

This is using Features and not Markers to display points.

I would now like to further extend that example to allow popups for individual points. I don't know exactly how to do that. The examples show adding a popup directly attached to a Marker.

Interestingly enough, the exact functionality I am looking for is located by viewing a geo json file directly from GitHub.

https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl/blob/master/projects/showcase/src/app/demo/examples/earthquakes.geo.json

Popups are displayed for individual points. I'm assuming those points are in the form of a Feature layer? Does anybody know where I can get the source for that viewer or help me with adding popups to Feature layer in ngx-mapbox-gl?

Thanks, Mike